# How to set a default email for devise login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Devise 3.1.1 and Rails 4

When a user clicks on a custom link, and the user is not logged in, I want to pre-populate the email field in the view for a custom login screen (value in the session). I've got a SessionsController method like below:

```
  def new
    # devise code seems to take this param, but it doesn't work
    params[:sign_in] = { 'email' => session[:sharing_email] }
    super
    # This is too late as view is already rendered.
    # I can put this in the view, but I'd rather do it in the controller
    # resource.email = session[:sharing_email] if session[:sharing_email].present?
  end
```

Should I just put this line in the view? It works fine.

```
resource.email = session[:sharing_email] if session[:sharing_email].present?
```

Is there any good way to get this into my controller before I call super? Note, resource does not exist before the call to super.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar and after reviewing the Devise source code I ended up using something like this:

```
def new
  build_resource({email: session[:sharing_email]})
  respond_with self.resource
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want default value for all user, the you can assign default value to column in rails.
If you are using activerecord, then do following

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :email, :default => 'default@email.com'
  ...
  t.timestamps
end
```

If you want it on controller level, then in new action , add

```
@user = User.new(email: session[:sharing_email])
```

Answer (score 0):

I've actually only used devise with Rails 3.2.  However, the parameter sanitizer (which differs for Rails <4 vs. 4) looks like the expectation for Rails 4 would be the same -- judging by the code in devise 3.1.2's parameter_sanitizer.rb, it looks like it expects the sign-in hash to be within a resource hash, rather than at the top level like in your example.

So if your resource is always user, you could get away with:

```
params[:user][:sign_in] = { 'email' => session[:sharing_email] }
```

or to be more generic/proper, something like:

```
params[resource_name.to_sym][:sign_in] = { 'email' => session[:sharing_email] }
```

should work (resource_name may be a symbol already; I can't remember offhand). (EDIT actually a string rather than a symbol would be fine I guess, as that's how it ends up in the form HTML - i.e. an input with the name `user[email]`).

The fact that it works in the view with the reference to resource.email makes me more certain that adding the extra resource level in the hash should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can pass email as the url param to the login page like that:

```
redirect_to user_session_path("user[email]" => "email@example.com")
```

or, if url is generated outside rails:

```
http://example.com/sign_in?user%5Bemail%5D=email%40example.com
```